# Best way to customize the structure of an Extjs 4+ field

Tags: javascript, extjs, field, custom-component

I'm interested in customizing an Extjs trigger field and I'm wondering what would be the best way to do the following (excuse the text diagram)(the square brackets represent the elements):

```
[field label] [trigger element] [button]
```

It is basically a trigger field with a small button appended to the end of it. I was hoping to just extend trigger field and perhaps add the button in through fieldSubTpl, ie:

```
fieldSubTpl: [
    '<input id="{id}" type="{type}" ',
        '<tpl if="name">name="{name}" </tpl>',
        '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>',
        '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>',
        'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off" />',
    '<div id="{cmpId}-triggerWrap" class="{triggerWrapCls}" role="presentation">',
        '{triggerEl}',
        '{buttonEl}',  <--- New Button Element
        '<div class="{clearCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
    '</div>',
    {
        compiled: true,
        disableFormats: true
    }
]
```

I would now love to be able to create an Ext.Button in the field's constructor and somehow use it for the {buttonEl}.
Full example:

```
Ext.define("Ext.ux.NewField", {
    extend: "Ext.form.field.Trigger",

    constructor: function(config) {
        config.newButton = Ext.create("Ext.button.Button", {
            /** ... button configs ... **/
        });

        Ext.applyIf(config, {
            fieldSubTpl: // as shown above
        });

        this.callParent([config]);
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();

        this.newButton.on("click", this.__onButtonClick, this);
    },

    getSubTplData: function() {
        var obj = this.callParent(arguments);
        obj.buttonEl = this.newButton.???????  <-- This is what I can't figure out
        return obj;
    },

    __onButtonClick: function() {
        // ...
    } 
});
```

How would I apply the default Ext button configs as well as those that I've overridden in the button constructor?  Is this even possible or is my use of templates here completely wrong?

Again, I would like to keep the "is-a" relationship of an Ext field, so just wrapping a trigger field and a button in an Ext.container.Container isn't a possibility for me.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: It's a little confusing what you're trying to ask. Do you want the HTML of the button that you created? If that's the case, then use `button.getEl().getHTML()`

Comment: Wrapping it in a container is the best solution, can you elaborate on why it's not a possibility?

Comment: @Evan Trimboli The field needs to keep the Extjs field api. It would be better if we didn't have to re-implement it all.

Comment: @VarunAchar At the time "getSubTplData" is called, the button element isn't rendered, so getEl() returns undefined. Maybe this isn't the way to do this...? Is there a vastly different way of achieving this field structure from extending from Trigger?

Comment: If you look at the `form.field.Field` mixin, there's actually not a lot to implement, you basically just need to cascade those calls down to the actual field.

Comment: I would advise not wrapping it in a container.  There are 27 methods on the mixin along with handling the various change events.  The real problems happen when using them in Forms.  You have to set the isFormField to false on the field you are wrapping around and set the that to true on the container even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very performant but this is possible to with childEls and or render selectors.

```
    Ext.define("Ext.ux.NewField", {
    extend: "Ext.form.field.Trigger",

    fieldSubTpl: [
        '<input id="{id}" type="{type}" ',
            '<tpl if="name">name="{name}" </tpl>',
            '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>',
            '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>',
            'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off" />',
        '<div id="{cmpId}-triggerWrap" class="{triggerWrapCls}" role="presentation">',
            '{triggerEl}',
            '<div class= "myButton"> </div>',  
            '<div class="{clearCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
        '</div>',
        {
            compiled: true,
            disableFormats: true
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        this.renderSelectors = {
            buttonEl: '.myButton'
        };
        this.newButton = new Ext.button.Button({
            text: 'New'
        });
        this.on('afterrender', function() {
            this.newButton.render(this.buttonEl);
        }, this);

        this.newButton.on("click", this.__onButtonClick, this);

        this.callParent();
    },

    __onButtonClick: function() {
        window.alert("new")
    } 
});
```

This actually renders the button below the input el so the template needs to get tweaked but the button is part of the field and rendered inside of its element.  The renderSelector is basically saying find the element that matches my '.myButton' when it renders and then set this.buttonEl to the associated Ext.Element.  The afterrender listener just renders a button to that element.  The render and rerender is mostly a no no on performance but it is much easier than having the overhead of a container that should behave like a field or writing the markup of a button inside of the render template.

EDIT to respond to comment:

getSubTplData is meant to gather the data that will be used by the XTemplate when its values are being applied.  If you did your example `{buttonEl}` would be replaced by `[object Object]`.  If you did something like `obj.buttonEl = this.newButton.id` it would replace the `{buttonEl}` with the button's id but that is not useful.  You example didn't work because your template didn't didn't give hooks for the button to render into and your `getSubTplData` has nothing to do with the rendering of the button.

Without messing with the render template you can do something like this to render a button below a trigger field.

```
Ext.define('CustomTrigger', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Trigger',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.btn = new Ext.Button({text: 'My Trigger'});
        this.on('afterrender', function(){
            this.btn.render(this.el.createChild());
        }, this)
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the example. It definitely gives me some insight on how this could be done, however I noticed that you are using button.render(..) which is only available in Extjs 4.1.3+ and I need to get this working on 4.0.7. Sorry I didn't mention that _major_ restriction :p. Am I way off on my original idea? Shouldn't I be able to assign the default button markup to the "buttonEl" property in getSubTplData? I just unsure as to where I can find the default Extjs button markup...

Comment: I am not sure why the documentation for 4.* render is different but `Ext.Component.render` has existed since Ext 1. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-render .  Every Component in 4.* has a render method.  You can even see it being used in their examples.  `ext-4.0.7/examples/themes/themes.js`

Comment: Ah.. sorry I do see it in AbstractComponent, however it's marked as private. I would definitely like to avoid using private functions if at all possible.

Comment: I would just use render, it has been publicly available in Ext 1,2 and 3 and still exists on 4.*  You can get the same behavior with the `renderTo` config but the order of how things are created would have to change to get it to work.  `render` is more flexible than `renderTo` that is why I use it.  http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-renderTo  This is actually in the docs : `When using this config, a call to render() is not required.`

Comment: Ok thanks.
Just for my own personal sanity, is my original suggestion using 'fieldSubTpl' and 'getSubTplData' even possible? Can you comment on that?

Comment: @j.learmond I responded to your comment by updating my answer. tldr; no